# Write external html page to fetch data from crm

Tags: html, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am working with crm 4.0.

I want to write an external HTML page to fetch records from an entity. This entity basically contains URL's. What i want to do is fetch these URL and set them as Hyperlink on the HTML Page.

So if the Record contains www.abc.com, the html page should show www.abc.com and when i click on it, it should direct me the that webite.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Is the page supposed to reside within CRM or are you talking about an external, external, really external web application that conneccts to the CRM server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the web services as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151038.aspx. If you are doing this with html you probably need to write the soap calls by hand which is pretty tedious work. I am no web developer though so that part is out of my league :)

Holler if you need more directions